# highcharts android click points?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, highcharts

Is this possible? If it isn't I'll be implementing another chart library this weekend, I haven't been able to get it going yet, but just want to check before wasting 10+ hours!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out through pain that the only version of Highcharts which supports point touch in Android is 1.26, so use that if you need this functionality, seems to work fine